# Asp.Net Core StateLess Serivce Calling StateLess Serice in Azue Service Fabric

Tags: service-fabric-stateless, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-on-premises

I am trying to call a stateless service from Asp.Net Core Stateless API. I am not able to reach the methods in Stateless Service.

This is the Controller action method which will call the stateless service method.

```
 // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<string> GetAsync()
    {
        var repository = ServiceProxy.Create<IRepository>(
            new Uri("fabric:/Application1/Stateless1"));
        return await repository.GetSomething();
        //return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
```

This is the method in Stateless service.

```
    internal sealed class Stateless1 : StatelessService, IRepository
    {
    public Stateless1(StatelessServiceContext context)
        : base(context)
    { }

    public async Task<string> GetSomething()
    {
        return await Task.FromResult("HELLO FROM SERVICE!");
    } 
    }
```

And the listener code is

```
protected override IEnumerable<ServiceInstanceListener> CreateServiceInstanceListeners()
    {
        return this.CreateServiceInstanceListeners();
    }
```

I am able to hit the controller Get method but it is struck at repository.GetSomething() method and not able to reach that method. I don't know what I am missing here.

Any pointers will be very helpful. Thanks in advance

Update:

Manifest file:

[image]

Comment: Could you also post the relevant bits of the `ServiceManifest.xml`? How certain are you that your `IRepository` service is actually running?

Comment: Updated above the manifest info. And I am just returning string from repository public async Task<string> GetSomething()
        {
            return await Task.FromResult("HELLO FROM SERVICE!");
        }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your CreateServiceInstanceListeners...

```
protected override IEnumerable<ServiceInstanceListener> CreateServiceInstanceListeners()
{
   return this.CreateServiceRemotingInstanceListeners();  
}
```

It needs the remoting listener as using the ServiceProxy is a remoting call.

Comment: Excellent. It worked. You saved me lot of time. Thanks